# add a UIToolbar as a UINavigationItem error

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar, uibuttonbaritem

I have a UIToolbar that sits at the bottom of the view. When the user is on an iPad, I want to add the toolbar to the right side of the navigation controller, because there will be room.

I added this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            UIBarButtonItem *toolBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:toolBar];
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = toolBarItem;
        }
[super viewDidLoad];
    }
```

But the application crashes with the error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. UINavigationBar's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.'
```

I don't know why this is a problem, because I have seen this method used before. By the way, the toolbar items are added in interface builder rather than using an NSArray of buttons, could that make a  difference?

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you normally declare the UIBarButtonItem?

Comment: plz show us the toolBar alloc and init codes.

Comment: and did you have [super viewDidLoad]; in your viewDidLoad method?

Comment: and where is the toolBar did you create?

Comment: @luyuan the toolbar exists as a regular toolbar at the bottom of the screen for the iPhone version. for the iPad version, I want to incorporate the toolbar into the navigation bar at the top. I added the uibarbuttonitems to the toolbar in interface builder.

Answer (score 0):

A UIBarButtonItem is one of the controls that lives inside a toolbar. Are you sure of what you're doing?  I can't follow what you're saying, but it seems like you are trying to add a toolbar inside a UIBarButtonItem.  It's supposed to be the other way around, UIbarButtonItem lives inside the UIToolbar

Comment: The UIToolbar contains several UIBarButtonItems, but I am trying to put the UIToolbar inside another UIBarButtonItem so that I can add it to the navigation bar. I didn't think there was an easier way.

Comment: The easier way is to create a custom UIView control that you can set the frame of arbitrarily.  What you're trying to do is UIToolbar Inception!